# php jpgraph page all white

Tags: php, jpgraph

I'm trying to load a bar plot example from [this](http://jpgraph.net/features/src/show-example.php?target=new_bar1.php) site:

This is my code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');

chdir("/path/lib/jpgraph-4.0.1");
include ("jpgraph.php");
include ("jpgraph_bar.php");


$data1y=array(47,80,40,116);
$data2y=array(61,30,82,105);
$data3y=array(115,50,70,93);


// Create the graph. These two calls are always required
$graph = new Graph(350,200,'auto');
$graph->SetScale("textlin");

$theme_class=new UniversalTheme;
$graph->SetTheme($theme_class);

$graph->yaxis->SetTickPositions(array(0,30,60,90,120,150), array(15,45,75,105,135));
$graph->SetBox(false);

$graph->ygrid->SetFill(false);
$graph->xaxis->SetTickLabels(array('A','B','C','D'));
$graph->yaxis->HideLine(false);
$graph->yaxis->HideTicks(false,false);

// Create the bar plots
$b1plot = new BarPlot($data1y);
$b2plot = new BarPlot($data2y);
$b3plot = new BarPlot($data3y);

// Create the grouped bar plot
$gbplot = new GroupBarPlot(array($b1plot,$b2plot,$b3plot));
// ...and add it to the graPH
$graph->Add($gbplot);


$b1plot->SetColor("white");
$b1plot->SetFillColor("#cc1111");

$b2plot->SetColor("white");
$b2plot->SetFillColor("#11cccc");

$b3plot->SetColor("white");
$b3plot->SetFillColor("#1111cc");

$graph->title->Set("Bar Plots");

// Display the graph
$graph->Stroke();
```

If I comment the line "`$graph->Stroke();`" the page is show (with no graph), but with this line the page is all white, no error, no other string is displayed

On php error log, or apache log I don't have error

***EDIT: Problem solved.***

I've put the chart code on other page (for example chart.php), than on principal page:

```
<img src="chart.php" />
```

Other solution is to create a png file whit command:

```
$myPicture->Render($fileName);
```

then on principal page

```
<img src="<?php echo $filename" />
```

Answer (score 1):

you must delete any space before the php 1st line in graph file beacause any blank line is considered as an echo ""; and the graph file should have no echo or print..etc.. then use the img tag in other file to show  the graph .. for me i named the file graph.php and i named the other stat.php and in the lats i wrote .. you can import data from mysql DB in the same graph file but never ^print them there . only use the array from DB as an income data to the graph..sorry i use english because my french is not that good

Comment: do you know why an echo statement will make graph not to display?

Answer (score 0):

add a slash at the end of the path you want to change to:

```
chdir("/path/lib/jpgraph-4.0.1/");
```

Comment: the problem is not in the path, but how I call the chart library